# How to escape ' in setParameter

Tags: php, javascript

I have a javascript function which is broken because the ' ('Côte d'Azur') is not escaped:

Javascript:searchDay('month', 'France', 'Côte d'Azur', '0', '201208', '18');

The parameters are set as followed:

```
$jsUrl = new JavascriptUrl(
        "searchDay",
        array("id", "country", "region", "city" , "month",  "startDay" )
        );      

$jsUrl->setParameter("id", "month");
$jsUrl->setParameter('month', $monthCode);
$jsUrl->setParameter('country', $countryName);
$jsUrl->setParameter('region', $regionName );
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: First and foremost, you must learn what **context** is all about. Next, you should learn to use **context-specific** functions. Functions like `addslashes`, `preg_replace` or `str_replace` are most often the wrong solution (unless you adhere to the context spec). For example, in your case, you should be using **json_encode** since you're throwing stuff in JS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try replacing any `'` in the string with `\'` in order to escape them as follows:

```
$regionName = str_replace("'", "\'", $regionName);
$jsUrl->setParameter('region', $regionName );
```

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but i think that one might be because of "\'" in the input escaping your escape so the single quote still terminates your JS string. Newlines are also an issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
('Côte d\'Azur')
```

or

```
("Côte d'Azur")
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for [**`addslashes()`**](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php).

> ```
> string addslashes ( string $str )
> ```
>
> Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be
>   quoted in database queries etc. These characters are single quote (`'`),
>   double quote (`"`), backslash (`\`) and `NUL` (the NULL byte).
>
> An example use of `addslashes()` is when you're entering data into a
>   database. For example, to insert the name O'reilly into a database,
>   you will need to escape it. It's highly recommended to use DBMS
>   specific escape function (e.g. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for MySQL
>   or `pg_escape_string()` for PostgreSQL), but if the DBMS you're using
>   doesn't have an escape function and the DBMS uses \ to escape special
>   chars, you can use this function. This would only be to get the data
>   into the database, the extra \ will not be inserted. Having the PHP
>   directive magic_quotes_sybase set to on will mean ' is instead escaped
>   with another '.